# Thevenin equivalent of the input of an op amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, thevenin

[image]

In the image above, the subcircuit in the box in the top circuit is reduced to the subcircuit in the light box below it using Thevenin's Theorem. I don't really see how to get a Thevenin equivalent out of the first circuit. I spent a while on it to no avail - could someone please give me a hand? How can you make a Thevenin equivalent of the subcircuit highlighted in the top circuit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a pretty much general method for finding the Thevenin equivalent circuit:

1. Find the open circuit output voltage. This means take the circuit you are trying to find the equivalent of, replace the load with an open circuit, and find the output voltage.

   In your circuit this means replacing everything to the right of node "B" with an open circuit. So the output voltage is given by the voltage divider rule,
   $$V_{oc} = v_s\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}$$
2. Find the short circuit output current. In your circuit this is given by
   $$I_{ss} = \frac{v_s}{R_1}$$

Now the Thevenin source voltage is \$V_{oc}\$ and the Thevenin resistance is \$\frac{V_{oc}}{I_{ss}}\$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how you got Voc. If you make it an open circuit, no current flows through the resistors therefore the voltage across the resistors is zero right?

Comment: It means you take the circuit you are trying to find the thevenin equivalent of, and you replace the **load** with an open circuit, then calculate the output voltage.

Comment: What would be the load in this case? Is it R3? If it is R3, wouldn't the OP AMP be part of the circuit that's being reduced since it's attached to one of the ends of R3?

Comment: It's whatever is the load for the circuit you are trying to find the Thevenin equivalent of. Since you are trying to get the equivalent of the circuit to the left of node "B", the load is everything to the right of node "B".

Comment: But if you use everything to the right of node "B" as the load, you would only have one terminal - the wire extending out of B. Don't you need two terminals to calculate the voltage across?

Comment: The ground node also connects between the "source" subcircuit and the "load" subcircuit.